# Making Live Clock javascript

Tags: php, javascript

does anyone know how to make live javascript time running..

i have this php code

```
    $expiredate = date('d m Y G:i:s', $rdate1);
    $f_ex_date = explode(" ", $expiredate);
    $f_ex_time = explode(":", $expiredate);
    $_endDate = mktime($f_ex_date[0],$f_ex_date[1],$f_ex_date[2],$f_ex_date[1],$f_ex_date[0],$f_ex_date[2]);
    $time = $_endDate - time();
    $days = floor($time/86400);
    $hours = floor(($time-($days*86400))/3600);
    $mins = floor (($time-($days*86400)-($hours*3600))/60);
    $secs = floor ($time-($days*86400)-($hours*3600)-($mins*60));

   echo "Your account going to be expired in <span style=\"color: #C11B17;font-family:arial;font-size: 16px;\">".$days."</span> Days <span style=\"color: #C11B17;font-family:arial;font-size: 16px;\">".$hours."</span> Hours <span style=\"color: #C11B17;font-family:arial;font-size: 16px;\">".$mins."</span> Minutes <span style=\"color: #C11B17;font-family:arial;font-size: 16px;\">".$secs."</span> Seconds";
```

is it possible to make it like running live??

Comment: Regarding the PHP, you might want to have a look at http://php.net/strftime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to do it. [**Working Demo**](http://www.rootspot.com/stackoverflow/timer.php).

First, at the top of your HTML document:

```
.datetime {
    color: #C11B17;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

We do this so we can clean up our HTML code a little bit:

```
$rdate1 = 1240550032; // Fri, 24 Apr 2009 05:13:52 GMT
$expiredate = date('d m Y G:i:s', $rdate1);
$time = $rdate1 - time();
$days = floor($time/86400);
$hours = floor(($time-($days*86400))/3600);
$mins = floor(($time-($days*86400)-($hours*3600))/60);
$secs = floor($time-($days*86400)-($hours*3600)-($mins*60));

printf("
    Your account is going to expire in
    <span class='datetime' id='days'>%s</span> Days
    <span class='datetime' id='hours'>%s</span> Hours
    <span class='datetime' id='minutes'>%s</span> Minutes
    <span class='datetime' id='seconds'>%s</span> Seconds
", $days, $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

I'm not quite sure where that middle step you were taking for came from, but the code above gets me the difference in time between `$rdate1` (presumably a unix timestamp) and `time()`.

Finally, we can do something like this with Javascript to update the time once the page loads:

```
addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    var eDays = document.getElementById('days');
    var eHours = document.getElementById('hours');
    var eMinutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
    var eSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
    var timer;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        var vDays = parseInt(eDays.innerHTML, 10);
        var vHours = parseInt(eHours.innerHTML, 10);
        var vMinutes = parseInt(eMinutes.innerHTML, 10);
        var vSeconds = parseInt(eSeconds.innerHTML, 10);

        vSeconds--;
        if(vSeconds < 0) {
            vSeconds = 59;
            vMinutes--;
            if(vMinutes < 0) {
                vMinutes = 59;
                vHours--;
                if(vHours < 0) {
                    vHours = 23;
                    vDays--;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(vSeconds == 0 &&
               vMinutes == 0 &&
               vHours == 0 &&
               vDays == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
        eSeconds.innerHTML = vSeconds;
        eMinutes.innerHTML = vMinutes;
        eHours.innerHTML = vHours;
        eDays.innerHTML = vDays;
    }, 1000);
});


function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
  } else
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's doable on the client with a little bit of JavaScript. Without using a framework such as jQuery, which would be of marginal help here, the basic method would be something similar to the following:

- Set up an event handler to fire each second

Within the event handler:

- Retrieve the current date and time and format it as desired
- Update the contents of another element with the new value

As a concrete example, the following function will set up a simple date/time update with a named element:

```
function clock( id ) {
    var target = document.getElementById( id );
    if( target ) {
        var callback = function() {
            var datetime = new Date().toLocaleString();
            target.innerHTML = datetime;
        };
    callback();
        window.setInterval( callback, 1000 );
    }
}
```

Note the use of [`new Date().toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2) to retrieve and format the current date/time; also, the use of [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to set up the callback to fire each second.

Comment: i'm very weak at javascript and basically don't know anything, do you know how to code it?

Comment: Keep in mind that this, and whatever clock js-based, will display the client time, not the server time

Comment: @DaNieL: Excellent point; any differences in time zone could affect the correctness of output, especially if (in this case) accounts are expired based on a local time on the server. One could add some offset calculation to adjust the time prior to formatting.

Answer (score 1):

PHP, since it is *[server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)*, can't be live. You'll have to do the date manipulation (at least, the stuff that changes) and update the DOM using JavaScript, which is *[client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)*.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

[JS-Clock](http://thiago-cavalcanti.github.com/JS-Clock/) is the best solution for live clock. it's mini JS version is of just only 4 KB. I recommend this.