# javascript clock with server time

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Live Clock javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763032/making-live-clock-javascript)

I want to create a clock, with javascript and php.
It should start from a server time (unix timestamp with php) and continue with javascript.
How can I create it?

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624239/clock-on-webpage-using-server-and-system-time/6624293#6624293), he said to use `Date.now();`, but this function return a timestamp with milliseconds, and php doesn't return milliseconds.

Help me, please.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get from php? If you get seconds, just multiply by 1000 and use `new Date()`

Comment: We can help you code, not code for you. Please give it a try, and if you are stuck then come here with your exact, specific problem. Don't ask as us invent the wheel for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to pass the current server time into the page as it's created, and use that to initialize your javascript clock. Thankfully, JS's Date object will accept a timestamp (in milliseconds) to initalize with, so it's as simple as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
</script>
```

Note the `* 1000` part. PHP's timestamps are in seconds, and JS's are in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has function returning miliseconds: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: That returns microseconds, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself and posted it on github if it can be useful:

https://github.com/Lwangaman/jQuery-Clock-Plugin

It uses jquery, it's basically a jquery plugin, and it can take a server timestamp to start with. The css can also be easily modified to one's own likings.

Answer (score -2):

could you not just do this? Why does the time need to come from the server?

```
<h4>It is now  
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
if (minutes < 10){
minutes = "0" + minutes
}
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
if(hours > 11){
document.write("PM")
} else {
document.write("AM")
}
//-->
</script>
</h4>
```