# PHP with javascript code, live clock

Tags: php, javascript

Hey I would to create a live clock to put it on my website. So I wrote a simple php with JavaScript code for that, here is it:

```
<?php
    Function d1() {  
        $time1 = Time();  
        $date1 = date("h:i:s A",$time1);  
        echo $date1;  
    }
?>  

<script type="text/javascript">   
    window.onload = startInterval;  
    function startInterval() {  
        setInterval("startTime();",1000);  
    }
    function startTime() {  
        document.getElementById('qwe').innerHTML = '<?php d1();?>';  
    }  
</script>  

<div id="qwe">test</div>
```

When run this code the output like `"2:40:17 PM"`, the `div` refreshed every second but the problem is the time never changed.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around `startTime` in your `setInterval` function? The quotes and the `()` are unnecessary as, `setInterval(startTime,1000);` would suffice.

Comment: Switched your references from "java" to "javascript", [they aren't the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) :)

Comment: PHP is a server side language. You would need to make a call to the server to do your function each time. Your code is compiled to have the same time displayed everytime. righ click -> view source

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780758/javascript-clock-with-server-time

Comment: in before 'use jQuery', as Anthony Forloney stated, remove the quotes and it will work.

Comment: Do you want the server's time or the client computer's time? They can be *very different*.

Comment: If you want to use the servers' time to start the clock that's fine but from that point on you'll want to use JavaScript.  Your function attempts to fetch the time from a PHP function on each interval which doesn't work as coded but would also be the wrong solution.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for your help, i tried to remove the qoutes and (), it does not work. Anthony Forloney

Comment: I want to display the server time.

Answer (score 5):

Get the initial time you want to start your clock with from PHP:

```
<script>
    var now = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
    function startInterval(){  
        setInterval('updateTime();', 1000);  
    }
    startInterval();//start it right away
    function updateTime(){
        var nowMS = now.getTime();
        nowMS += 1000;
        now.setTime(nowMS);
        var clock = document.getElementById('qwe');
        if(clock){
            clock.innerHTML = now.toTimeString();//adjust to suit
        }
    } 
</script>
```

For formatting the date there's a zillion options (MDN Date API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: The format i want to display it's like "h:MM:ss TT", How can i change your code for that?

Comment: +1 for using dead reckoning and not polling the server every second.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function timedMsg()
  {
    var t=setInterval("change_time();",1000);
  }
 function change_time()
 {
   var d = new Date();
   var curr_hour = d.getHours();
   var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
   var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();
   if(curr_hour > 12)
     curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
   document.getElementById('Hour').innerHTML =curr_hour+':';
    document.getElementById('Minut').innerHTML=curr_min+':';
    document.getElementById('Second').innerHTML=curr_sec;
 }
timedMsg();   
</script>

 <table>
   <tr>
  <td>Current time is :</td>

  <td id="Hour" style="color:green;font-size:large;"></td>
  <td id="Minut" style="color:green;font-size:x-large;"></td>
  <td id="Second" style="color:red;font-size:xx-large;"></td>
  <tr>
 </table>
```

use this way to display time........
enjoy the above script

Comment: To display "0" when needed i added the <script> with the following:                                                             
                    
                        curr_min = checkTime(curr_min);
                        curr_sec = checkTime(curr_sec);
                       
                       
                    function checkTime(i) {
                        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
                        return i;
                    }

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to refresh the time:

Example:

```
<?php
if(@$_GET["action"]=="getTime"){
  $time1 = Time();  
  $date1 = date("h:i:s A",$time1);  
  echo $date1; // time output for ajax request
  die();  
}
?>

<div id="qwe">test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
  window.onload = startInterval;  
  function startInterval() {  
    setInterval("startTime();",1000);  
  }
  function startTime() {
    AX = new ajaxObject("?action=getTime", showTime)
    AX.update(); // start Ajax Request   
  } 
  // CallBack 
  function showTime( data ){
    document.getElementById('qwe').innerHTML = data;
  }  
</script>  



<script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax Object - Constructor
function ajaxObject(url, callbackFunction) {
  var that=this;
  this.updating = false;
  this.abort = function() {
    if (that.updating) {
      that.updating=false;
      that.AJAX.abort();
      that.AJAX=null;
    }
  };
  this.update =
  function(passData,postMethod) {
    if (that.updating) { return false; }
    that.AJAX = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      that.AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
      that.AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (that.AJAX==null) {
      return false;
    }else{
      that.AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (that.AJAX.readyState==4) {
          that.updating=false;
          that.callback( that.AJAX.responseText, that.AJAX.status, that.AJAX.responseXML, that.AJAX.getAllResponseHeaders() );
          that.AJAX=null;
        }
      };
      that.updating = new Date();
      if (/post/i.test(postMethod)) {
        var uri=urlCall+(/\?/i.test(urlCall)?'&':'?')+'timestamp='+that.updating.getTime();
        that.AJAX.open("POST", uri, true);
        that.AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        that.AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", passData.length);
        that.AJAX.send(passData);
      }else{
        var uri=urlCall+(/\?/i.test(urlCall)?'&':'?')+passData+'&timestamp='+(that.updating.getTime());
        that.AJAX.open("GET", uri, true);
        that.AJAX.send(null);
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
  var urlCall = url;
  this.callback = callbackFunction || function (){};
}
</script>
```