# Autoupdate java clock, time formatting

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format

```
<div id="clock"></div>

<script>
var now = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
function startInterval(){  
    setInterval('updateTime();', 1000);  
}
startInterval();//start it right away
function updateTime(){
    var nowMS = now.getTime();
    nowMS += 1000;
    now.setTime(nowMS);
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    if(clock){
        clock.innerHTML = now.toTimeString();//adjust to suit
    }
}
```

This is my html code. I am a Java noob and basically found this here: [PHP with javascript code, live clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563234/php-with-javascript-code-live-clock). I want to adjust the format from "HH:mm:ss GMT+0100 (Romansk (normaltid))" to only "HH:mm:ss".

Comment: JavaScript is not Java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
now.toLocaleTimeString(false, {'hour12': false});
```

or instead of `false` - your prefered locale

Answer (score 1):

Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
clock.innerHTML = moment(now).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/3LXG4/).

BTW, you are using PHP `time()` to return server side time right? Just a hint, `setInterval` is not that accurate (see: [How Accurate is Window.setInterval()](http://www.goat1000.com/2011/03/23/how-accurate-is-window.setinterval.html)) and so you will slowly introduce imprecision. If client side clock can't be trusted I would either expose the server time as Web Service or consume the time from one of the many web services already available ([Time API](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json), [json-time](http://json-time.appspot.com/), etc). While there will be a delay, at least it will not introduce cumulative imprecision.