# Format PHP and Javascript clock

Tags: javascript, php

I took this code from [PHP with javascript code, live clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563234/php-with-javascript-code-live-clock) , and successfully put it on my website.
The code is here:

```
<?php
function d1() {
    $time1 = time();

    $date1 = date("h:i:sa",$time1);
    echo $date1;
}
?>
<script>
    var now = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
    function startInterval(){
        setInterval('updateTime();', 1000);
    }
    startInterval();//start it right away
    function updateTime(){
        var nowMS = now.getTime();
        nowMS += 1000;
        now.setTime(nowMS);
        var clock = document.getElementById('qwe');
        if(clock){
            clock.innerHTML = now.toTimeString();//adjust to suit
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="qwe"></div>
```

However, the time format shows up as this:

```
21:41:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

I want it to show up as

```
9:41:44 PM
```

I assume that this line

```
 clock.innerHTML = now.toTimeString();//adjust to suit
```

is the one I need to change, but can't find any formats that show it very simply. Do I need to write something up myself to show it in this custom format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript this should solve your problem

Comment: thank you, thank you, I can't believe I didn't find this before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to suggest you try to use Developer tools in Chrome so you could examine what are the properties and functions available for an object.

Try this, F12 to the developer tool and in there type

```
var date_new = new Date()
```

then type date_new. after pressing that dot, you'll see what potential functions are available to you

[image]

Of course, its good to read on official documentation to know all about this, but in case you don't have internet connection or in a hurry. you can just look around at those functions of Date Object.

Have fun coding!

Comment: Btw momentJs is also easy to use and quite lightweight already. But sometimes pure JavaScript rocks too :)

Comment: I tried momentJs, for some reason it isn't working I have it here http://jsfiddle.net/0qze164t/ can you help me identify what is wrong here? did I incorrectly download moment.js?

Comment: Code school has a free course on devTools for chrome. https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do something like this.

```
function formatTime(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; 

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
}

// your existing code with modification
...
clock.innerHTML = formatTime(now);//adjust to suit
...
```

If you happen to be working with date time too much and are having to use functions like above, you should consider using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).