# Send php date to javascript and increment it

Tags: javascript, php, clock

I want to get the server time using php, and pass it to a javascript variable. 
Once it is passed, it will increment.

Here is my code:

```
function initTime(date){
var today=new Date(date);
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
}
function checkTime(i) {
if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}
```

Situation: 
The user browse welcome page, the server time is sent and received by javascript.

I want to increment it, to make it a clock script. I don't want to get the server time every second using php, because it will use more server resources.

How can I increment it using javascript?

Comment: Just `echo` your server time directly as a value for your JavaScript variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript clock with server time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780758/javascript-clock-with-server-time)

Comment: I got the server time correctly. My problem is, How Can i increment it? For example, i got, 21:33:01, I want to make it 21:33:02 after a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just output the PHP date somewhere, either in a global variable, or as a data attribute somewhere you can get it

```
<div id="time" data-now="<?php echo time() * 1000; ?>"></div>
```

and then

```
var elem  = document.getElementById('time');
var timer = setInterval(initTime, 1000);

function initTime() {
    var time = +(elem.getAttribute('data-now')),
    time = time + 1000; // add one second

    var today = new Date( time ),
        h = today.getHours(),
        m = today.getMinutes(),
        s = today.getSeconds();

        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);

    elem.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    elem.setAttribute('data-now', today.getTime());
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
    }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eruoq20r/)

Answer (score 1):

You can put your php variable in an hidden input :

`<input id="your_input" value="<?php echo $my_var; ?>">`

and get it in javascript with :

`my_var = document.getElementById('your_input').value;`

Answer (score 1):

Two ways. First, using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
},1000);
```

or using your function:

```
function initTime(date){
var today=new Date(date);
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
}
function checkTime(i) {
if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}

setInterval(initTime(date),1000);
```

Comment: It still not changing.

Comment: What does the console log?

Comment: I got the server time correctly. My problem is, How Can i increment it? For example, i got, 21:33:01, I want to make it 21:33:02 after a minute

Answer (score 1):

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780758/javascript-clock-with-server-time) that was basically after the same thing.  The initialized the JS date using the milliseconds from php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
</script>
```

Here is a jQuery [clock plugin](https://github.com/Lwangaman/jQuery-Clock-Plugin) that you can use that you can feed a starting time to(your server time).  Putting it all together, it would go something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
    $("#clock").clock({"timestamp":d.getTime()});
</script>
```

Comment: If you believe the questions are asking the same think flag it as a duplicate.